# force logfile switch

Tags: logs

I believe something is wrong with my log file in uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog. (civi was looking for a file without the timestamp so I removed the timestamp from the matching log file) Is it possible to force civi to create a new log file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I removed the timestamp from the matching log file

It doesn't break anything to do that, but for reference the ones with the timestamps are old logs that have been rotated and just kept for archiving.

> Is it possible to force civi to create a new log file

It will do it on its own when there's something new to log, as long as the web server user (e.g. apache/www-data/etc) has write access to the folder. It probably does if it rotated old logs.

Note if you're using the logviewer extension and it says "unable to open file" (or something) which is what led you to all this, then that's a known issue with the extension, because there isn't a way to tell the difference between just "no new log entries yet" and "file is missing/error".

On the other hand if you were expecting new entries, then check folder permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is a new installation of civi resulting from a fresh install of wordpress and civi on Azure followed by an import of the database from our old hosting provider.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is a new installation of civi resulting from a fresh install of wordpress and civi on Azure followed by an import of the database from our old hosting provider. www-data has write access to the log folder. There  is one timestamped log file and two very large logs that are not timestamped. The logs are so large because I had left Debug and Error on for another problem. Both logs without timestamps stop logging on 31 August which is the latest data that log viewer reports on. Any further help you can offer would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have `cv` installed you could do `cv ev '$f
 = CRM_Core_Error::createDebugLogger(); echo $f->_filename;'` which will tell you where it thinks the log file is. Perhaps something changed in the config in the move.

Comment: You were right with your earlier post, it was an ownership problem and now that I have managed to cause something to be written it is working ok. Thank you